# How can I refer to a control from within a control's method (like the "me" for classes)?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, controls

How can I refer to the control while I am inside a control's method in VB.NET?

For example, I want in a textbox to show a message box with that textbox's text every time the text changes. The code would be something like:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

msgbox("The text is:"+ Me.text)    

' ok the line above wont work i already know that, because "Me" refer to the form,
' not the control textbox1
' how i will refer to the textbox1's text???
' i dont want to use "textbox1.text" is there a way similar like the "Me" is for forms?
' because i want to copy-paste a code like this in a lot of controls and do not want to
' have to change in every copy the name to each control name

End Sub
```

I hope I made myself clear; my English needs some improvement :D

Comment: i tried searching for "MyBase, Parent, Me" but i didnt find anything that will self-reffer for controls... :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no keyword that allows you to do that. However, every event raised by a control passes in a `sender` parameter that you can use to determine which particular control raised that event.

Note that this parameter is always typed as a basic `Object` (because it can represent any possible control), so you'll need to downcast to a more specific control class if you need to access any of the unique members that it exposes. Since you're handling an event raised by a `TextBox` control, you know that the `sender` *must* be of type `TextBox`, so you can simply use [`DirectCast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k6y2h6x.aspx) to handle the upcasting. You don't have to worry that an `InvalidCastException` will be thrown.

For instance, your above example would become:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Dim textBox As TextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
    MessageBox.Show("The text is: " & textBox.Text)
End Sub
```

---

That being said, there are a couple of concerning things that jump out at me in your question:

1. Any time that your approach to solving a problem is "copy-pasting" code, you should stop, take a step back, and try to figure out if there's any better way to achieve your ultimate goal.

   For example, if you need *every* textbox on your form to react in the same way whenever a particular event is raised, you should consider subclassing the existing `TextBox` control and consolidating all of your code in one place. Remember that you can inherit off of most of the standard controls to add custom functionality. This is often a far better solution than copying and pasting code to multiple places in your project. If you ever need to track down a bug or modify that functionality, you'll only have to change it one place in your code, rather than several. As a somewhat cheekier benefit, you'll be able to use `Me` to refer to that control when you're editing its subclass.
2. You should always prefer to concatenate (combine) strings using the `&` operator in VB.NET, rather than the `+` sign. Or perhaps even better, the [`String.Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.concat.aspx) or [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) methods.
3. There is no reason to use `MsgBox` in VB.NET, as opposed to [`MessageBox.Show`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show.aspx). No, this won't improve performance of your application, but it's a good practice to get into for .NET languages.

Comment: +1 Although I would also consider [extender providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6c1xa43.aspx) rather than subclassing TextBox.

Comment: @MarkJ: Of course, depending on the specific need. I just felt like I was already getting a little far off-topic. ;-)

Comment: I think you were right on-topic when you identified "copy-pasting code like this in a lot of controls" as a warning sign. "If you use copy and paste while you're coding, you're probably committing a design error." [David Parnas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Parnas)

Comment: "To a more specific control class" is a downcast, not upcast.

Comment: i also agree with your comments, i believe i should downcast the textbox control as soon as i finish debugging the extra functions that i create for the textboxes. thank you again for all your answers and recommendations. all of them are pointing to the correct practice of programming and i appreciate your help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The sender variable contains the TextBox instance you want to access. You only need to convert the sender to TextBox.